# Can requesting too much links break the website with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a youtube project with selenium, I am requesting every 30 sec a new link, but after like 10 links, the comment section keep on loading, and never load, I checked the internet, copied the same link and paste it in another browser, but worked fine, so can scraping too much links affect the website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.

You cannot keep scraping the site continuously. They have systems in place which detect these kinds of activities and block those requests.

I would recommend you to use **YouTube API** to fetch the data you need.

Comment: But what if I want to comment on more than 1 video, can this api help me

Comment: I think [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) can help

Comment: Comment is in the supported Operation so I will research more and come back

Answer (score 0):

yes, Youtube comment is not meant for scraping. Google has a bot that would detect this activity and your script would not be able to scrape it at all.

Did you try with proxy server ? It could be a shot, but I would not recommend you to spam it, anyway they are gonna detect it.